# converting rows of a single dataFrame column into a single list in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series and I would like to covert all the rows of my series into a single list. I have:

```
list1=Series([89.34,88.52,104.19,186.84,198.15,208.88]). Then I have a function which i call:
func(list1)
def func(list1):
   list1=list1.values.tolist()
   print(list1)
```

the printed result is :

```
[[89.34], [88.52], [104.19], [186.84], [198.15], [208.88]]
```

but I would like to have :
`[89.34,88.52,104.19,186.84,198.15,208.88]`

any help. I am using python 2.7

Comment: You should not use `list` as a variable name because it a globally accessible data structure.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem you had. Could you add python version, pandas version and what OS you use?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how that code would give that result.  If you had a *DataFrame*, and then called `.values.tolist()`, you'd get a list of lists, but if you have a Series, you should  simply get a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to access the `values` property of the `Series` object, like you have in your example.

```
> from pandas import Series
> a_series = Series([89.34,88.52,104.19,186.84,198.15,208.88])
> print(a_series.values.tolist())
[89.34, 88.52, 104.19, 186.84, 198.15, 208.88]
```

Accessing more than one elements in the list at the same time:

```
> counter = 0
> a_list = a_series.values.tolist()
> while(counter < len(a_list)):
..    if((counter+1) < len(a_list)):
..        print(a_list[counter] == a_list[counter+1])
..    counter+=1
False
False
False
False
False
```

Comment: Thanks Ray,the problem with this is that i would like to iterate through that list starting at the second index; that is your elem+1 and compare it with elem

Comment: Then you don't need to you a list. You can do more efficiently with pandas objects. Use ```b_series = a_series.shift(-1)``` to create series that has the same indexes, only the data is shifted. Then you can use for example ```a_series - b_series``` to get the difference

Comment: I added a way to compare elements to previous elements.  If I am mistaken please let me know.  Any logic requirements (like comparing elem+1 to elem) should be in your question so there is no confusion.

Comment: @Ray i have a curious question though; assuming it was a DataFrame and that i am passing just one column; how will it work?

Comment: You would have to add another loop inside the while loop since you would then be iterating over "columns" and "rows".  Unless pandas has a built-in that makes this easier.  I'm not that familiar with pandas to be honest. The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable) have a few interesting methods mentioned (like [DataFrame.applymap](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap)) that may work.